# How to mapping and grouping an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have this data, and i want to mapping this data without using lodash

```
let temp = [{
    "2020": 0,
    "2021": 0,
    "Series": "Check Qty Plunger Lub"
  },
  {
    "2020": 1,
    "2021": 4,
    "Series": "Cleaning 5MK"
  }
];
```

and i want to remapping the object like this

```
[
    2020 : {
        Series : 2020,
        Check Qty Plunger Lub : 0,
        Cleaning 5MK : 1,
    },
    2021 : {
        Series : 2021,
        Check Qty Plunger Lub : 0,
        Cleaning 5MK : 4,
    },
    etc ..
]
```

the key is using year, and inside the year object is have dynamic keys using `temp.series`, and value is following the temp object

example  :
Check qty plunger lub have 0 value on 2020, and 0 on 2021 so the object must

```
    2020 : {
        Series : 2020,
        Check Qty Plunger Lub : 0,
        ...
    },
```

Comment: The desired output is a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array.

```js
const
    data = [{ 2020: 0, 2021: 0, Series: "Check Qty Plunger Lub" }, { 2020: 1, 2021: 4, Series: "Cleaning 5MK" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { Series: key, ...rest }) => {
        Object.entries(rest).forEach(([Series, v]) => {
            r[Series] ??= { Series, [key]: 0 };
            r[Series][key] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```